# datatables/yadcf with new api isn´t working with dom-onclick

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am using datatables, yadcf-plugin and exResetAllFilters to reset all column filters.

I recently switched to the "new api" (yadcf.init), but *dom onclick* isn´t working anymore.
Error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

I know I can do it with *$("#reset2").click*, but I am interested to understand why isn´t working anymore.

For better explaination, I made two samples: http://live.datatables.net/yavayasa/2/edit and http://live.datatables.net/xofaluli/3/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not related to yadcf, in that example you declared your `table` variable inside your `$(document).ready( function () {` function and since js `var` is *lives inside teh function scope* it will be undefined for calls made outside of that function,

Solution: declare your `table` variable outside the function, [see example](http://live.datatables.net/xofaluli/4/edit)

```
var table;
$(document).ready( function () {
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it very much.